# Chamar um preloader antes de enviar contato

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte form e suas validações. Como eu faria para chamar um gif (preloader) para o formulário no momento que o usuário clica para enviar. Ele deve sumir quando o ajax for concluído.

```js
function solucoesForm() {

  if ($.trim($('#soluctionsName').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsName').val()) == 'Nome') alert('Informe seu nome!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsEmail').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsEmail').val()) == 'E-mail') alert('Informe seu e-mail!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsPhone').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsPhone').val()) == 'Telefone') alert('Informe seu telefone!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsEmpresa').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsEmpresa').val()) == 'Empresa') alert('Informe a Empresa!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsCidade').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsCidade').val()) == 'Cidade') alert('Informe sua Cidade!');
  else {
    $.post('carregamentos/solucoes.php',
      $('#solucoesFormulario').serialize(),
      function(abc) {
        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
      }
    );
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact soluctionsForm margin-top-190 margin-bottom-110" id="solucoesFormulario" action="" name="solucoesFormulario" method="post" onsubmit="return solucoesForm();">
  <div class="grid_380 float-left">
    <div class="margin-bottom-30">
      <h2>Solicite um orçamento</h2>
      <h2>para esta solução</h2>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="margin-bottom-20 grid_380" name="Nome" placeholder="Nome" id="soluctionsName" />
    <input type="text" class="margin-bottom-20 grid_380" name="E-mail" placeholder="E-mail" id="soluctionsEmail" />
    <input type="text" class="margin-bottom-20 grid_380" name="Telefone" placeholder="Telefone" id="soluctionsPhone" />
    <input type="text" class="margin-bottom-20 grid_380" name="Empresa" placeholder="Empresa" id="soluctionsEmpresa" />
    <input type="text" class="grid_380" name="Cidade" placeholder="Cidade" id="soluctionsCidade" />
    <input class="grid_380 margin-top-25" type="submit" name="Enviar" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro usares `$.ajax` em vêz de `$.post`, pois o primeiro tem um método para isso. Ou seja é mais completo. Podias usar assim:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "carregamentos/solucoes.php",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $('#divOndeQueresMostrarPreload').html('preload.gif');
    },
    data: $('#solucoesFormulario').serialize(),
    success: function (abc) {
        // "Mensagem enviada com sucesso", logo, o processo do post acaba aqui, já podemos retirar a imagem.
        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
    }
});
```

Outra sugestão para fazer essa validação:

```
function solucoesForm() {
    var toValidate {
        soluctionsName: 'Nome',
        soluctionsEmail: 'E-mail',
        soluctionsPhone: 'Telefone',
        soluctionsCidade: 'Cidade',
        soluctionsEmpresa: 'Empresa'
    }
    var validated = true;
    Object.keys(toValidate).forEach(function (key) {
        if (!validated) return;
        var val = $.trim(document.getElementById(key).value);
        if (val && val != toValidate[key]) return;
        alert('Por favor complete o campo ' + key);
        validated = false;
    });

    if (validated) $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "carregamentos/solucoes.php",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $('#divOndeQueresMostrarPreload').html('preload.gif');
        },
        data: $('#solucoesFormulario').serialize(),
        success: function (abc) {
            // "Mensagem enviada com sucesso", logo, o processo do post acaba aqui, já podemos retirar a imagem.
            alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você quer o código para fazer o gif aparecer? Creio que isso seja responsabilidade sua, o que procura deve ser a lógica. Ela é bem simples, você quer que uma imagem apareça ao clicar para enviar, e quando acabar, que ela suma, não é? Você pode exibir a imagem após a validação estiver concluída, antes de realizar o `post`, assim é dada uma resposta imediata ao usuário de que algo está sendo feito.
Após isso, você precisa aguardar o `post` ser completado. Em seu exemplo você já mostrou quando ele é completado, logo, é lá que deve ser colocado o comando para a imagem sumir.

```
function solucoesForm() {
  if ($.trim($('#soluctionsName').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsName').val()) == 'Nome') alert('Informe seu nome!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsEmail').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsEmail').val()) == 'E-mail') alert('Informe seu e-mail!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsPhone').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsPhone').val()) == 'Telefone') alert('Informe seu telefone!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsEmpresa').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsEmpresa').val()) == 'Empresa') alert('Informe a Empresa!');
  else if ($.trim($('#soluctionsCidade').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#soluctionsCidade').val()) == 'Cidade') alert('Informe sua Cidade!');
  else {
    // Fomulário validade, exibe uma mensagem de carregamento
    $.post('carregamentos/solucoes.php',
      $('#solucoesFormulario').serialize(),
      function(abc) {
        // "Mensagem enviada com sucesso", logo, o processo do post acaba aqui, já podemos retirar a imagem.
        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
      }
    );
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um bloco no seu documento HTML contendo o conteúdo que será mostrado no momento da requisição. Por exemplo:

```
// foo.css
.imagem-carregando { visibility: hidden }

// foo.html
<img class='imgem-carregando' src='imagem.gif'>
```

Bastaria então no momento da requisição você tornar alterar a regra desse elemento para `visibility:visible`.

Para isso, pode utilizar a função `$.ajax` que possui mais eventos para controlar a requisição, definindo o que deve ser feito antes e/ou depois desta ser enviada - [$.ajax events](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#solucoesFormulario").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: "carregamentos/solucoes.php",
      type: "post",
      data: data,
      
      // chamada antes de enviar a requisição
      // alteramos para mostra a imagem
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $(".carregando").css('visibility', 'visible');
      },
      
      // chamada quando a requisição termina (seja com erro ou OK)
      // alteramos e escondemos a imagem
      complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        $(".carregando").css('visibility', 'hidden');
      },
      
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.carregando{ visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class='carregando' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwRrg.gif' alt='' />
<form id="solucoesFormulario" action="#">
  <!--
    inputs
  -->
  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```