# Como colocar Janela modal com gif no formulário?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Possuo um formulário que programei utilizando PHPMailer e eu gostaria que quando o usuário preenchesse os campos e clicasse em enviar, ao invés de redirecionar para uma outra pagina de agradecimento eu queria que fosse exibida uma espécie de "*dialog*" ou melhor dizendo uma janelinha modal com um texto de agradecimento dentro. E também antes de aparecer o modal queria que fosse exibido um gif na tela por alguns segundos indicando que o formulário esta sendo enviado.

Dei uma olhada nesse [post aqui](http://www.wbruno.com.br/ajax/enviar-formulario-para-php-sem-refresh-jquery-ajax/), e meu código ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function () {
                var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "contato.php",
                    data: dados,
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div id="formulario">
    <form action="email.php" method="POST" id="ajax_form">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="Nome" id="nome" placeholder="  Digite seu nome" required name=nome  maxlength="50"></li>
            <li><input  type="email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="  Digite seu Email" required name=email maxlength="100"></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="Nickname" placeholder="  Digite seu Nickname" required name=nickname maxlength="20"></li>
            <li>
                <select name="Games">
                    <option value ="the-elder" selected>  --- Selecione um jogo ---</option>
                    <option value ="the-elder">The Elder Scrols Online</option>
                    <option value ="archage">ArcheAge</option>
                    <option value ="worlofwarcraft">World of War Craft </option>
                    <option value ="forsaken">Forsaken World</option>
                    <option value ="leagueoflegends">League of Legends</option>
                    <option value ="dota">Dota 2</option>
                    <option value ="smite">Smite</option>
                    <option value ="warface">Warface</option>
                    <option value ="cs">CS-GO</option>
                    <option value ="bf">Battle Field</option>
                    <option value ="cod">Call of Dutty</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li><textarea placeholder="  Mensagem" name="Mensagem" required name=mensagem maxlength="300"></textarea></li>
            <li><input type=submit value="Enviar" id="enviar" name="Enviar"/></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Quando clico em enviar aparece isso na minha tela:
[image]

Comment: Seria interessante você colocar os testes que fez como tentou fazer entende

Comment: entao eu possuo um codigo amigo porem nao faço ideia de como implementa-lo tenho esse codigo comigo so nao sei como usar neste caso,

Comment: bom o seu código atual é algo simplesmente copiado de outra pergunta sua ... é interessante colocar testes que fez ate aonde chegou.... da forma que esta sua pergunta esta tipo ... Façam por mim ... isso ninguém vai fazer

Comment: ok amigo vou editar a minha pergunta para melhor entendimento so um segundo irei postar tbm meu codigo do dialog para poder ficar melhor

Comment: @Otto amigo editei meu npost e coloquei meu codigo do dialog em html para ver como ele foi feito e se tem alguma maneira de implementa-lo no meu botao de enviar

Comment: Então ja é alguma coisa, bom da uma olhada nesse post do Bruno http://www.wbruno.com.br/ajax/enviar-formulario-para-php-sem-refresh-jquery-ajax/, eu acho uma forma de implementação muito melhor utilizando ajax para isso

Comment: amig segui os passos la do link que voce me passou e editei novamente meu post da uma olhadinha da um erro estranho alias se isso foe um erro sahsuasa

Comment: Cara, você já fez algumas 4 derivações dessa mesma pergunta. Seria melhor você pelo menos tentar procurar o minimo antes de perguntar... Bom, comece tirando o  `alert( data );` depois do `success`, logo depois procure sobre [modal em ajax](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ajax+loading+modal), pra colocar exatamente no lugar do `alert( data );` , existe diversos tipos de modais dependendo do seu gosto.

Comment: Você tem várias perguntas em uma única, confuso não!? A questão de mostrar uma imagem enquanto o formulário é enviado já foi [respondido aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59711/4808) pelo Sergio. Agora, quanto ao seu código, notou que os atributos `name` dos seus *inputs* não possuem aspas? Estão `name=foo` quando deveria ser `name="foo"`. Conserte isto e veja se resolve o seu problema. :)